# How to merge two list items with matching substrings and add the other substring together?

Tags: python, list

I do have a list that looks like this (just shortened it for the sake of this post, since it is really long):

```
[<Cell R105C123 1>, <Cell R27C123 8>, <Cell R139C115 1>, <Cell R139C115 1>, <Cell R19C111 2>, <Cell R19C119 2>]
```

Let's say there are two items on this list of which the Substring matches until the last number, for example:

```
<Cell R66C127 0.5>, <Cell R66C127 1>
```

I need to merge two of them into just one item, in this case:

```
<Cell R66C127 1.5>
```

I do believe that list comprehension has to be used, however, my experience with it is really limited, how can this be done?

Comment: In general you cannot use list comprehension for accumulating tasks. Also could you please add the type of the elements of the list? Are the elements to be merged alwyas contigous?

Comment: Your sample does not represent valid Python code

Answer (score 0):

One approach, is to use collections.defaultdict to aggregate the results and then built the result list from it:

```
from collections import defaultdict

lst = ["<Cell R105C123 1>", "<Cell R27C123 8>", "<Cell R139C115 1>",
       "<Cell R139C115 1>", "<Cell R19C111 2>", "<Cell R19C119 2>",
       "<Cell R66C127 0.5>", "<Cell R66C127 1>"]

lookup = defaultdict(float)
for e in lst:
   _, key, value = e.strip("<>").split()
   lookup[key] += float(value)

res = [f"<Cell {key} {value}>" for key, value in lookup.items()]
print(res)
```

**Output**

```
['<Cell R105C123 1.0>', '<Cell R27C123 8.0>', '<Cell R139C115 2.0>', '<Cell R19C111 2.0>', '<Cell R19C119 2.0>', '<Cell R66C127 1.5>']
```

Note that the above approach is a general solution, if the elements to be merged are always contiguous use itertools.groupby:

```
from itertools import groupby

lst = ["<Cell R105C123 1>", "<Cell R27C123 8>", "<Cell R139C115 1>",
       "<Cell R139C115 1>", "<Cell R19C111 2>", "<Cell R19C119 2>",
       "<Cell R66C127 0.5>", "<Cell R66C127 1>"]


def key(e):
    _, k, _ = e.strip("<>").split()
    return k


def value(e):
    _, _, v = e.strip("<>").split()
    return float(v)


res = [f"<Cell {key} {sum(map(value, group))}>" for key, group in groupby(lst, key=key)]
print(res)
```

**Output**

```
['<Cell R105C123 1.0>', '<Cell R27C123 8.0>', '<Cell R139C115 2.0>', '<Cell R19C111 2.0>', '<Cell R19C119 2.0>', '<Cell R66C127 1.5>']
```